# How to make a scatterplot showing correlation between a single gene vs multiple genes?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, scatter-plot

I have a matrix with samples as rows and Genes as columns with gene expression values (RPKM).

Following is an Example data. Original data has more than 800 samples.

```
        LINP1   EGFR            RB1       TP53         CDKN2A      MYC
Sample1 0.02   0.038798682  0.1423662   2.778587067 0.471403939 18.93687655
Sample2 0      0.059227225  0.208765213 0.818810739 0.353671882 1.379027685
Sample3 0      0.052116384  0.230437735 2.535040249 0.504061015 9.773089223
Sample4 0.06   0.199264618  0.261100548 2.516963635 0.63659138  11.01441624
Sample5 0      0.123521916  0.273330986 2.751309388 0.623572499 34.0563519
Sample6 0      0.128767634  0.263491811 2.882878373 0.359322715 13.02402045
Sample7 0      0.080097356  0.234511372 3.568192768 0.386217698 9.068928569
Sample8 0      0.017421323  0.247775683 5.109428797 0.068760572 15.7490551
Sample9 0      2.10281137   0.401582013 8.202902242 0.140596724 60.25989178
```

To make a scatter plot showing correlation between two genes I used `ggscatter`

```
ggscatter(A2, x = "LINP1", y = "EGFR", 
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = FALSE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "LINP1", ylab = "EGFR", xscale="log2", yscale="log2")
```

The scatter plot looks like this

[image: scatterplot]

And I want to make a scatter plot like this

[image: scatterplot]

Fig 2g in this [Research paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4927085/). where LINP1 expression is showed against all other genes in a single plot. Is it possible with any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are doing pearson correlations, the results are the same as if you did a scatterplot and plotted a fitted line from a regression model which can be accomplished in `ggplot2::geom_smooth()` in conjunction with your scatterplot by genes.

Edit:
Updated to use a log2() transformation on both scales per the OP's comment. Note that when doing transformations you can sometimes get invalid values. Your data has `0`s so a log2() transformation returns `-Inf`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(text = "
LINP1   EGFR            RB1       TP53         CDKN2A      MYC
Sample1 0.02   0.038798682  0.1423662   2.778587067 0.471403939 18.93687655
Sample2 0      0.059227225  0.208765213 0.818810739 0.353671882 1.379027685
Sample3 0      0.052116384  0.230437735 2.535040249 0.504061015 9.773089223
Sample4 0.06   0.199264618  0.261100548 2.516963635 0.63659138  11.01441624
Sample5 0      0.123521916  0.273330986 2.751309388 0.623572499 34.0563519
Sample6 0      0.128767634  0.263491811 2.882878373 0.359322715 13.02402045
Sample7 0      0.080097356  0.234511372 3.568192768 0.386217698 9.068928569
Sample8 0      0.017421323  0.247775683 5.109428797 0.068760572 15.7490551
Sample9 0      2.10281137   0.401582013 8.202902242 0.140596724 60.25989178", header = TRUE)



df %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = values, EGFR:MYC) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(LINP1, values)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2") + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2")
```

[image]

Comment: From this plot how can I tell it is positively/negatively correlated? I need similar plot like I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @beginner - The charts are scatter plots / correlation plots: it's positively correlated if the line goes from bottom left to upper right and negatively correlated if it goes upper left to lower right.
The charts I provided are like those provided in the paper your mentioned. I fail to see a difference.

Comment: yes this is right. And Is there a way to scale the values? like in my plot I did log2 scaling.

Comment: @beginner - Yes. You can add the line  `+ scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2")`. Check the help for `scale_y_continuous()` as there are numerous transformations available. if you want to transform the x axis then you would call `scale_y_continuous`. Do you want me to up date my post to show this?

Comment: yes please update your answer. I want both the axes to be log2 scaled.

Comment: @beginner - Updated the post per your request. Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it's answering your question.

Comment: Yes it is correct. one small help again. In the plot I generated [https://imgur.com/a/Xdh2ADO] I don't want those numbers to be there on x and y axes. How to get rid of them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174452/discussion-between-mhammer-and-beginner).